# Compiler errors (resolving) when compiling after addition of Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am adding FCM push notifications to an Angular (v8.2.0) website. Thought I followed simple instructions in the docs exactly, but when I compile, it throws a ton of resolution errors. If I just add the Admin SDK (`npm i firebase-admin` gave me v8.3.0) it compiled fine. But when I added the import and a few lines of code, compiling blew up.

I've been searching on Stack Overflow, Git hub, and pretty much everywhere else I can but don't see this type of problem. Here's the code snippet lifted right off the docs:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

   // The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
   var topic = 'abc';

   var message = {
      data: {
         score: '850',
         time: '2:45'
      },
      topic: topic
   };

   // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
   admin.messaging().send(message)
      .then((response) => {
         // Response is a message ID string.
         console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
```

It's been very consistent though:

> Install SDK: Compiles OK
>
> Add import: Compiles OK
>
> Call admin (anything): Compiler errors
>
> Comment out admin (anything): Compiler errors
>
> Uninstall Admin SDK: Compiles OK

There are around 100 or so errors like below:

```
ERROR operationsClientBrowser Can't resolve googleauth graceful-fs aws-sign2 index
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Projects\GitHub\mozaportal\node_modules\aws-sign2'
ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Projects\GitHub\mozaportal\node_modules\aws4'
ERROR in ./node_modules/crypto-random-string/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Projects\GitHub\mozaportal\node_modules\crypto-random-string'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Projects\GitHub\mozaportal\node_modules\ecc-jsbn'
...
```

I also tried submitting a ticket to the Firebase team, but the web submission has had error for the last 12 hours when trying to submit.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I didn't understand the documentation correctly:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging states that it needs:

> A trusted environment such as Cloud Functions for Firebase or an app server on which to build, target, and send messages

The Firebase Admin SDK is server-side only and I was just using Angular. Needed to add Node.js or some other server-side functionality to use the SDK. Or, as I'm opting to do, use Google's Cloud Functions to pass FCM to.